# On which Intel CPUs can I use umonitor and umwait instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, instruction-set

These [instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) are supported by CPU's with the `WAITPKG` CPUID bit, but what if any CPUs have that?

Comment: Slated for Tremont (next gen after Goldmont plus), if it's not out yet.  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/tremont and https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-V3-Intel-UMWAIT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Intel Architecture Instruction Set Extensions and Future Features Programming Reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf), these instructions will be introduced with the Tremont microarchitecture.

Answer (score 1):

WAITPKG first appeared in low-power Tremont, the next generation after Goldmont Plus.

Later in Golden Cove cores in Sapphire Rapids (server) and  Alder Lake (client).
[ADL P-cores are Golden Cove, E-cores are Gracemont](https://superuser.com/questions/1677692/what-are-performance-and-efficiency-cores-in-intels-12th-generation-alder-lake/1677779#1677779), so WAITPKG is part of the common subset of features and thus can be enabled, unlike AVX-512.

https://www.phoronix.com/news/GCC11-SapphireRapids-AlderLake confirms that Intel's GCC patches added the feature for `-march=sapphirerapids` and `-march=alderlake`